# Sizing images separately when stating limit(#).each do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, image-size

I've set up a page where you can view my users' listings in/as collections, calling the first 3 images they upload to display and limiting the number of images called to 3. I'm looking now to be able to take the first of those 3 images and size it much larger than the other 2 which I want to keep as thumbnails underneath. Much like Etsy's homepage for Trending Items.

What is the best solution for being able to custom size images when called in #-at-at-time through:

```
<% user.pictures.limit(3).each do |picture| %>
   <%= image_tag picture.image.url(:thumb) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read correctly, the question could be reduced to given a list of items, how to do something special to the first one than the others. `each_with_index` is one of the ways.

```
<% user.pictures.limit(3).each_with_index do |picture, i| %>
   <% if i == 0 %>
     # Make it the big one
     <%= image_tag picture.image.url %>
   <% else %>
     # Make it smaller
     <%= image_tag picture.image.url(:thumb) %>
<% end %>
```

Above it an illustration assuming `image.url` without `:thumb` returns a bigger image. If you need more precise control over location and size of the images, I'd suggest render the first image and others with different HTML elements/classes so that you may apply different CSS to them.